# Can I read webpage data using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a way to automate the testing, web page data filling, and also wanted to extract web page data and get them stored into our database permanent basis. Is there any way to fulfil such requirement using Ruby? If so, please guide me to what Ruby modules can help me.

Comment: Check out mechanize http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html

Comment: `+1` for the help and link. Now could you say what version of Ruby I need to install and does package you mentioned would come by default with Ruby when I installed or separately I have to install that?

Comment: You definately should install a ruby version manager first, to be able to easy choose between the versions. Since you're a beginner, install RVM https://rvm.io/ , later on install ruby 1.9.3, and then, install the mechanize gem . We can't simply write you here an article for that what we learned and examined for years... try out this config and you will be on the right track. If anybody thinks rbenv is better... maybe, but it makes no difference for you at this stage, later when you more experienced, you can decide by yourself

Comment: @astropanic I am using Windows 7 . Will that operating system support me to do what I am looking for? Put your all suggestions in a answer post,so that I can up vote you :)

Comment: didn't you get an acceptable answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do all this tasks using Ruby and some gems.
I recommend you to take a look at `Nokogiri gem` for data extraction: 
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri
And `Capybara gem` for testing and automation of forms and stuff:
https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

P.S.: Capybara gem does much more than just this, but it can be applied to your case too.

Comment: what version of `Ruby` would support this and any installation guide you want to refer?

Comment: Any versions of ruby support this gems. But you might want to install a newer one for better support. The github pages of both gems contains good examples and tutorials that you can use. =]

Comment: `+1` to you also to show your interest to my pain.Any guideline to installation part such `Nokogiri` and `Capybara` on windows 7 machine?

Comment: I have never used windows as a programming environment. But i guess you can install the gems the same way as any unix env. Beware for problems with some C extensions of the gems. I have read about it and it may happen.

Comment: Then how to overcome such problems?

Comment: in my cases the devtools http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/ solved the native-problems under windows.

Answer (score 1):

Since some Webpages may not be valid XML, you are also able to use Regular Expressions to fetch the data you want from a webpage. Sometimes a XMLReader-approach just fails.

Sample:

```
require 'open-uri'
page_content = open("http://your_page.com").read
page_body = page_content.scan(/<body>(.*)<\/body>/i).first
# do whatever you want with it
```

As VBSlover said, capybara is useful to deal with browsing related stuff.

Doing this in an automated way every n minutes or the like is also possible with the whenever gem.

For handling Database-Storing there are plenty of very good gems out there.

Final answer: there is nothing you can't do with Ruby nowadays. Okay, maybe except writing some really (!) high-performance code / 3D-Engines.

**Edit:** 
if you can tell what you exactly want to do i may suggest you some matching gems.
Usually "There is a gem for it" is a good saying. you can browse rubygems.org for some keywords you need, or look at https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/ for some categorized/ranked suggestions for your problem. :)

**EDIT 2:**
have a look at http://watir.com/ 
maybe just play around with it in some little painless scripts to get a feeling for it and if it is the solution for you.

> Watir drives browsers the same way people do. It clicks links, fills
>   in forms, presses buttons. Watir also checks results, such as whether
>   expected text appears on the page.

Once you have it clicked everything for you, just scrape the results (or whatever you need) from the webpage, using some XML-Parser (nokogiri would be a good choice) or some regexp's.

Then stuff your data in your database. Activerecord comes to mind for this, but it may or may not be overkill. depending on your database, choose whatever adapter/connection gem you like (again: there are MANY).

If you want to do this every hour or the like, just use the whenever gem (manages a cronjob for you) or simply write a infinite loop with sleep(x) in it if you want. There is more than one way to do it. :)

Comment: Yes, Thanks to show your feelings to my pain. `+1` for that.Once again I am mentioning here what I would want. I am using Third party web application, where we are doing some monotonous task. Now I want to automate everything, say testing,extracting data from the webpage and also development. That application is nothing but SaaS tool where we create request form and workflows - everything by clicking only. Any more information if you want I am happy to share you!

Comment: Last time when I tried i failed with `watir` installations also,tried more,took help from internet but the result was `ZERO`. So in that context Ruby I can Install,after that whatelse I need to do with that installations? any guideline? :)

Comment: Ruby comes with a build-in package manager called RubyGems. go to your CLI and just type "gem install XXX", and after some second it should be there. After that, just "require 'XXX'" in your script. That's it. If you have any problems with this basic stuff, please post your OS, ruby-version (and/or RVM version). And the steps you did and which error occurs when.

Comment: Does ruby support `Firefox 13` and If so, then what I need to install for that?

Comment: Ruby is a programming language, i don't know what you mean with "support" Firefox? If you mean the watir-library: http://watirwebdriver.com/ says that Firefox, Chrome, IE and Safari out of the box.

Comment: So your question is wrong, you don't want read a webpage (get the contents), you want automate a browser interaction with a webpage, yes ? http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/

Comment: Yes you are right! But what does it mean by `webpage read`? means how it differs from reading `webpage content`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a proper operation system, either use Linux or BSD or MacOS.

Windows will fit for some people, but not for you as ruby developer, too much libraries need c extensions with are pain in the ass to compile under cygwin.

I recommend, install a Ruby version manager, so you can try out different ruby versions, I prefer RVM, the Ruby Version Manager.

Install Ruby 1.9.3 it is the standard nowadays.

Trough rubygems install the gem mechanize, with does pretty all automation for websites you will need. It is a successor of LWP::Mechanize from Perl.

Nokogiri would be also useful, for parsing XML data like (X)HTML, but remember you should have prior libxml libs installed on your system.

Ah, according to your question:

Yes, you can read websites using ruby, for example read this webpage:

```
http = HTTPClient.new
http.get "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235393/can-i-read-webpage-data-using-ruby"
```

Done

Comment: `+1` to you first. Now I have no chioce as my Organization using `Windows PC (7/XP)`

Comment: What do you mean Your organization is using... ? No way of using dual boot option or WUBI installer ? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

You can also buy for a month or two a SSH accessible host for about 5 bucks

Comment: Windows for Ruby development is fine for most cases, thanks to devtools for C-Extensions (available at the rubyinstaller page). Due to some reasons ruby is somewhat slower than eg: ubuntu linux, but who cares in most cases... Also if he may use JRuby, it doesn't really play a role which OS he is using.

Comment: a) Have you ever seen a real production environment serving Ruby applications from Windows ?

b) "most cases" is not enough, either you should be able to get the full potential of the language, or it makes no sense using it

Comment: development environment must not in every case match the production environment. i use ruby & jruby on a daily basis on several machines (including windows vista, win7, win XP, ubuntu (several), archlinux, and even on my android device). sure, linux per se is WAY better for developing, but windows is mostly good enough. simply depends on what you're doing.

Comment: The WAY better is fair enoug for me to be agains windows installation. And especially a beginner should not begin wit Ruby development under Windows

Comment: one advantage of ruby is being crossplatform ;) just start with the platform you're comfortable with, so you can focus on ruby itself, not  your whole environment.

Comment: yeah, and never learn how to fork properly, managing system resourcers or communication via ...unix sockets. Read this http://workingwithunixprocesses.com/ , Ruby is crossplatform, but all his libraries where it strength comes from definately not, but this discussion makes no sense, so I wish you good luck on your Win environment and many succesful projects.

Comment: again: everything you mentioned has nothing todo with the OP's question. And: don't get me wrong: i develop mostly with linux. But in most cases, one just doesn't need that specific libraries you mentioned. Exspecially as a beginner like the OP. got it?